# Mongoimport json file update or overwritte ..?

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoimport

I'm having DB which name is "Project" and collection which name is "sample" then I inserted one JSON file using `mongoimport` command.

Now i edited the same JSON file. So if want to import the same JSON file to the Collection then I am facing the problem like multiple instances are created and no updating is not taking place.

Is there any way to update  or overwrite the data already present in the mongodb using `mongoimport` command ?

Note that I also tried using `--mode=upsert` flag:

```
./mongoimport --db Project --collection sample --mode=upsert --file   /home/rule.json
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For MongoDB v3.x,

```
--mode=upsert
```

Answer (score 12):

**--drop**  flag also can be used along with mongoimport command to overwrite/update the existing data.

```
--drop


./mongoimport --db Project --collection sample --drop --file   /home/UCSC_rule.json
```

I gave this solution because i have tried using **--upsert** flag but i could not see any changes in the existing data instead new instance was created.

Comment: Note that `--drop` remove the whole collection before importing the data from the json file, while `--mode=upsert` insert the new keys and updates the existing ones.

Answer (score 7):

Default behavior says skip if already exists
so by default it wont overwrite existing data.

But you can update it using `--upsert` flag.

Comment: ok, i want to  erase and re-import so if i use `upsert` it'si good for me ?

Comment: you can use upsert which will overwrite the existing. (erase+ import = overwrite with new data.) Let me know if you need something different.

Comment: not working i use --upsert a the end of my command line but when i do a db.stats() the numbers of objects increase

Answer (score 2):

Based on the mongo doc, the reason --mode=upsert doesn't work in your case is by default, mongoimport uses the _id field. So --drop should be the correct answer.

--mode=upsert:

> By default, mongoimport uses the _id field to match documents in the
>   collection with documents in the import file. To specify the fields
>   against which to match existing documents for the upsert and merge
>   modes, use --upsertFields.

--drop:

> Modifies the import process so that the target instance drops the
>   collection before importing the data from the input.

[mongoimport document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/)

Answer (score 1):

`--mode upsert`  will create a new record if _id's don't match. These _id's are preserved across db's on different machines by mongodump/mongorestore

`--drop` will delete the entire collection!

To overwrite one or more records without dropping other existing records, ensure the id's match when using `--upsert`

Answer (score 0):

Using MongoDb version 3.6.8 the following solution worked to me

```
mongoimport --db <db name> --collection <collection name> --upsert --upsertFields <field name>  --file <path to json file> --jsonArray
```

Where "field name" was the name of key used by MongoDb to compare instead of the default field "_id".

Answer (score 0):

I'm on version 1.40.3 and now you can finally do it without a CMD.

Update the data on the cell and click the UPDATE button on the right bottom.

If you have a lot of data, it may be hidden and you may have to scroll down to see it.

[image: Where to find UPDATE button on MongoDB Compass]